How to integrate custom protoc plugin with bazel?
I wrote a protoc plugin to generate custom .h and .cpp files, it works well in command-line.
protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-foo=plugin_foo.py --foo_out=output bar.proto

My project is build with bazel, how can I integrate my plugin with it?
Something what I want is like cc_proto_library, generate files with my plugin and compile them as cc_library.
I have found proto_lang_toolchain in bazel documents, it has a attribute called plugin, but I still don't know how to use it after read its description...
